Mass-attack of Amazon bots
Gday folks. Recently we discovered a significant spike in outgoing data on our web-server.
It turns out Amazon bots are downloading our web imagery, a lot. We set a disallow in our Robots.txt, over a week ago but it is being ignored.
We found it difficult to pinpoint this through IIS logs, so installed Netlimiter which quickly pointed to several key Amazon IP addresses. I was able to mitigate some of this by blocking several Amazonbot user agents, however I'm now finding more IP addresses that are not using typical Amazon user agents.
An example of this is: 34.209.16.240 Go-http-client/1.1
I don't want to go and block this user-agent, and I don't necessarily want to block individual IP addresses.
What would be the recommended path to follow here?

Collect logs and report the issue to abuse@amazonaws.com.

herewith as cee correctly stated, contact Amazon for abuse as stated below
NetHandle:      NET-34-192-0-0-1
OrgID:          AT-88-Z
Parent:         NET-34-0-0-0-0
NetName:        AT-88-Z
NetRange:       34.192.0.0 - 34.255.255.255
NetType:        allocation
RegDate:        2016-09-12
Updated:        2016-09-12
Source:         ARIN


OrgID:          AT-88-Z
OrgName:        Amazon Technologies Inc.
CanAllocate:    
Street:         410 Terry Ave N.
City:           Seattle
State/Prov:     WA
Country:        US
PostalCode:     98109
Comment:        All abuse reports MUST include:
Comment:        * src IP
Comment:        * dest IP (your IP)
Comment:        * dest port
Comment:        * Accurate date/timestamp and timezone of activity
Comment:        * Intensity/frequency (short log extracts)
Comment:        * Your contact details (phone and email) Without these we will be unable to identify the correct owner of the IP address at that point in time.
RegDate:        2011-12-08
Updated:        2024-01-24
OrgAdminHandle: IPMAN40-ARIN
OrgTechHandle:  ANO24-ARIN
OrgAbuseHandle: AEA8-ARIN
OrgNOCHandle:   AANO1-ARIN
OrgRoutingHandle:   ARMP-ARIN
OrgRoutingHandle:   IPROU3-ARIN
Source:         ARIN

